# The requested address is not valid in its context in TCP socket communication

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I want to implement socket communication between two applications running on the same PC. One of the is a Unity application (server). So I wrote the following:

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
        Int32 port = 8800;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");

        // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr,port);
        Socket socketForClient;

        try
        {
            server.Start();
            socketForClient = server.AcceptSocket();
            if (socketForClient.Connected)
            {
                print("connected");
            }
            else
            {
                print("not connected");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            print(e.Message);
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

When I am starting the game I am getting the following: `The requested address is not valid in its context.` exception. Any help? Which IP / Port should I use if I want server client run on the same PC?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen on `0.0.0.0` which would be all interfaces including loopback and external.

But if you know it is the same machine, use `127.0.0.1` as it is always pointing back to itself.

Answer (score 1):

According to [IPAddress Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.ipaddress_fields%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use `IPAddress.Loopback` for the local loopback interface. If you want to establish a connection on any interface you can use `IPAddress.Any`.

In your solution you might have problems if the local IP address changes and isn't 192.168.1.1 anymore - therefore you should rather use one of the possibilities provided by the framework (like Loopback or Any).

Comment: I changed it to `IPAddress.Any` but when I trying to run it frozes.

Comment: I guess it "frozes" at `server.AcceptSocket()`, right? That would be because the call to `server.AcceptSocket()` is blocking. It will block as long as there is no connection established.

Btw: In my opinion you should start a background thread that endless listens until someone or something tries to connect and then starts another worker thread for this connection.

Comment: So, I guess if I create the client and start it assuming the connection will be established, it will be no frozen any more. Right?